# Classic ASP - Windows Vista - IIS7 - Permission issue

Tags: iis, iis-7

I've installed II7 + ASP Classic on my Vista business pc as I want to develop my own pctools (automate some boring manual tasks).

Unfortunately, every time I try to WRITE into a .txt file I get this error:

```
Path out = C:\Users\Carlos\Storage\bpmbck.txt

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied

/pctools/cleanfb.asp, line 53 

Line 53 contains set fileout = fs.OpenTextFile(pathout, ForWriting)
```

Given that I'm running as an ADMIN and that the target folder is owned by me, I don't understand why this is happening.

I've googled the net to find a similar basic problem (write to a text file) but I only find more complex ones (databases, mail, etc..).

An can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are you running the IIS process as admin?

Answer (score 1):

The identity/account for the application pool under which the site is running needs to have write permissions to that folder.

This is different from the user you are logged in as.

Answer (score 0):

Give "users" WRITE access to the folder.